# Explain why the x value is not updated in this racket language code?

Tags: racket

This code:

```lisp
(let ((x 2)) (let((f (lambda (n)(+ x n )))) (let (( x 17)) (f 3 ))))
```

is giving me the answer 5, why isn't the x value updated from 2 to 17?

Answer (score 0):

The magic of [Lexical Scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope).

Here's a version with comments:

```lisp
(let ((x 2))
  ; x is bound to 2
  (let ((f (lambda (n) (+ x n))))
    ; f is bound to a function that adds `x` and a number `n`
    (let ((x 17)) (f 3))))
    ; Bind `x` to 17, call (f 3) in the body.
```

In the third line, the name `x` is bound to 17. But the previous `let` already bound `f` to add `2` and a fresh number `n`. This demonstrates the same idea:

```lisp
(let ((f (λ (n) (+ 2 n))))
  (let ((x 17)) (f 3)))
```

Comment: @YAwwad Lexical scoping - when a lambda/function is defined - the x "catches" the x  visible for the lambda - 2. So `f` is defined by this function body using `x = 2`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining .This question appeared to my quiz

Answer (score 0):

Your later binding of x to 17 is irrelevant because x is bound to 2 in the environment that f is written in. When evaluating function calls, always look at the function definition's environment, not the function call's.